# How to get all information about particular transaction type?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-composer

I am developing Hyperledger composer application and I am querying the historian and get following response.

```
{
  "$class": "org.hyperledger.composer.system.HistorianRecord",
  "transactionId": "0010a094a2d554b37896649f31b827936958038726a86171f80b508a03873f8e",
  "transactionType": "org.hyperledger.composer.system.AddParticipant",
  "transactionInvoked": "resource:org.hyperledger.composer.system.AddParticipant#0010a094a2d554b37896649f31b827936958038726a86171f80b508a03873f8e",
  "participantInvoking": "resource:org.hyperledger.composer.system.NetworkAdmin#admin",
  "identityUsed": "resource:org.hyperledger.composer.system.Identity#b2875576ddcc5dde2f1b674e22055a43d3ca4d218795edda21e3a7566c904ee8",
  "eventsEmitted": [],
  "transactionTimestamp": "2018-09-20T06:59:12.271Z"
}
```

As mentioned in the above response transaction type is about add participant.In here i want to know which participant is added(more information) like in the composer playground 'All Transactions' interface.

[image]

As an example when I click the 'view record' it should be displayed the details of participant added. How  can i do it?

Answer (score 0):

You can get the same information as the Playground *view record* by querying the `org.hyperledger.composer.system.AddParticipant` registry, and you can narrow down by using the `transactionId` or `targetRegistry` in the WHERE clause.

Comment: yes, that is true but the problem is, this table is generated dynamically and next record may be UpdateAsset transaction. Therefore I have to query org .hyperledger.composer.system.UpdateAsset. How I check the transaction type and query the corresponding registry of those transactions generated? or can I dynamically change the target registry when executes queries?